# User creation error in Liferay

Tags: active-directory, liferay

I am trying to export users from Liferay to Active Directory. Import works fine. After i have set the options for export I am not able to create user in Liferay.

I am receiving error like ,

```
08:04:38,269 ERROR [http-bio-8086-exec-4][render_portlet_jsp:154] com.liferay.portal.ModelListenerException: javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090C30, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v1db0]; remaining name 'cn=Rose,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com'
at com.liferay.portal.model.UserListener.onAfterCreate(UserListener.java:65)
at com.liferay.portal.model.UserListener.onAfterCreate(UserListener.java:1)
at com.liferay.portal.model.BaseModelListener.onAfterCreate(BaseModelListener.java:1)
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.update(BasePersistenceImpl.java:261)
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.update(BasePersistenceImpl.java:277)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.addUserWithWorkflow(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:753)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
```

I am unable to resolve this error past one week. Please suggest me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Karthick

Comment: Have you find any solution for this???

Comment: No, still I haven't find it. Pradit, do you the solution for this?

Comment: I am also not finding. Within short period of time, I will find it...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a re-indexing of the users.

You can run the reindex users from the control panel:

In the `Plugins Installation` section, under `Portlet Plugins` tab, locate **`Users and Organizations`** and click on **Reindex** button